# HTTP to HTTPS redirection for same domain running under two different port

Tags: apache, ssl, server

I have two websites with the server name say, `abc.example.com` and `abc.example.com:70`. I'm using Apache as a web server.

I have redirected `abc.example.com` from port 80 to 443. This application is working well.

For the application with the server name `abc.example.com:70`, I have installed the configuration under virtualhost:70 and enabled the SSL engine. Finally, https has been enabled successfully for the application with server name `abc.example.com:70`. But when I hit the same website `abc.example.com:70`with HTTP, it is not redirecting to https. I tried enabling HTTP to HTTPS redirect rule, but it is not redirecting.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You can't have both HTTP and HTTPS site running on the same port with the same name, on the same IP address.

Comment: @DusanBajic Will it be possible to create a global redirect for all the name which enters to the server?

Comment: The short answer is no. Perhaps if you if you elaborate why do you need this, there might be a sensible solution.

Comment: @DusanBajic I've two application. One is for external use. The other will be loaded into iframe with the external app. I don't want to use different subdomain names for each.

Comment: If it is an iframe, you get to pick the scheme/port, why do you need a redirect?

Comment: Sometimes admin users may use the URL directly in the browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159746/discussion-between-sathishkumar-jayaraj-and-dusan-bajic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't have both HTTP and HTTPS site running on the same port with the same name, on the same IP address.